# C - freeing up memory after 2D array

Tags: arrays, c, free

I'm having a problem. I created a 2D array, and in the end, i would like to free it. Where's the problem in my code?
If i run my program everything works fine, until the end. It never prints out Succes!, so I think it bugs out before that point. Any help?
[image]
Here's my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n=5;
    int size=51;
    char **a_name=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        a_name[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
        scanf("%s",a_name[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%s\n",a_name[i]);
    }
    n=6;
    *a_name=realloc(*a_name,sizeof(char*)*n);
    scanf("%s",a_name[n-1]);
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%s\n",a_name[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        free(a_name[i]);
    }
    free(a_name);
    printf("Succes!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*a_name=realloc(*a_name` remove those `*`

Comment: The last element is never allocated. you need   a_name[n-1] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);

Comment: `char** a_name` reads as a pointer, to a pointer to char. Realloc accepts a pointer. Thereby you pass `a_name`. The extra * is dereferencing it and passing a pointer to char instead.

Comment: Please save us the trouble of seeing your screenshots.  Paste the output text directly into the question.  The thousands of pixels in that screenshot do nothing to help understand the question, they only obfuscate the output at the bottom, which should have been preserved in its text form.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, change

```
*a_name = realloc(*a_name, sizeof(char*) * n);
```

to

```
a_name = (char**)realloc(a_name, sizeof(char*) * n);
```

You don't want to reallocate the contents of the array of strings (`a_name`) to one of the strings itself (`*a_name`).

Secondly, the source of the problem is that after you called the realloc, you didn't call malloc on the *newly added* elements of `a_name` like you did here:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    a_name[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size); // here you allocated a 51 byte block for each char*
    scanf("%s", a_name[i]);
}
```

The sixth element of the array is a dynamically allocated pointer, but the array of chars *it points to* hasn't been allocated the 51 bytes you allocated for the first 5 strings.

The solution is to add this line before the second scanf call

```
a_name[n - 1] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
```

Your final code should look like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    int size = 51;

    char **a_name = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*n); 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a_name[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
        scanf("%s", a_name[i]);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", a_name[i]);
    }

    n = 6;
    a_name = (char**)realloc(a_name, sizeof(char*) * n);
    a_name[n - 1] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size); // allocate memory for the string first
    scanf("%s", a_name[n - 1]);
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", a_name[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free(a_name[i]);
    }
    free(a_name);
    printf("Success!\n");
    return 0;
}
```